# QuickGraph Metro style application support

Tags: c#, .net, microsoft-metro, quickgraph

I would like to use QuickGraph library in a Win8 Metro style application.
However I didn't manage to reference it in a freshly created app. I used the simple blank app template. I tried to install it via Nuget, I get the following error:

Install failed. Rolling back...
Could not install package 'QuickGraph 3.6.61119.7'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETCore,Version=v4.5', but the package does not contain any assembly references that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.

Does anyone managed to use it in .NET 4.5?

Thank you in advance
Adam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to their page, they don't support .NET Framework 4.5 (required for Metro Apps), so probably that's why you're having this problem.

> ◾.NET 2.0, 3.5, 4.0 or Silverlight 3.0